# qpython+pygame Segmentation fault

Tags: android, pygame, qpython

I am install on Nexus 5 QPython and trying run this code:

```
import pygame

size = width, height = 400, 400

window = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption('hello, pygame!')

screen = pygame.Surface((400,400))

done = True
while done:
  for e in pygame.event.get():
    if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
      done = False
  screen.fill((0,255,0))

  window.blit(screen, (0,0))
  pygame.display.flip()
```

after run, i am see this:
[image]

but, if i am rinning this code onto PC, thats OK

Answer (score 0):

**QPython 2.4.2**
You need to add

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:pygame
```

as  the first and second line to include the qpython version of pygame
if the problem persists please try to add your qpython version and interpreter version